# regular expression issue, maybe related to greedy match

Tags: regex, scala

```
val a="""\s*(abc)?.*(xyz)?""".r
val a(x,y)="   abcxyz"
```

I expect y is xyz,  but actually it's null, how could I extract xyz? It's optional, but if it's there then I want to extract it.

```
scala> val a="""\s*(abc)?.*(xyz)?""".r
a: scala.util.matching.Regex = \s*(abc)?.*(xyz)?

scala> val a(x,y)="   abcxyz"
x: String = abc
y: String = null
```

Comment: try `"""\s*(abc)?.*?(xyz)?""".r`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the ".*".

It consumes the whole match before reaching "(xyz)".

You could add "?" to the Kleene-Star in order to make the match non greedy ".*?".

```
val a="""\s*(abc)?.*?(xyz)?""".r
//a: scala.util.matching.Regex = \s*(abc)?.*?(xyz)?

val a(x,y)="   abcxyz"
//x: String = abc
//y: String = xyz
```